# Create css rule in web developer tools

Tags: css, firefox, firefox-developer-tools

The command I by far use the most in Firebug is right-clicking in the CSS pane and "Add Rule..."

Is there any quick equivalent in Firefox's Web Developer tools?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We've just added this to Firefox 33, see [this bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=966895) for more info.

To try it out right now, download Firefox Aurora from http://aurora.mozilla.org/

Answer (score 1):

Click on style editor tab. And add your css there.

Answer (score 0):

Where it says:

```
element {
}
```

you should be able to just click there and add a rule. If the element has inline styles already applied to it, those braces won't be empty but you can do that same thing.

Comment: Yea that's for inline right? The command "Add rule..." in firebug let's you name a selector, declare the rules and then copy the whole thing with "Copy Rule Decleration" and paste it in your file. Is there an equivalent efficient procedure in FF tools?

Comment: But how do you add a rule with a different selector?